# What difference between paragraphSpacing and paragraphSpacingBefore? (in NSMutableParagraphStyle)

Tags: ios, nsparagraphstyle

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMutableParagraphStyle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMutableParagraphStyle/paragraphSpacing

I read already this post.

But I can't understanding exactly.

What the difference between paragraphSpacing and paragraphSpacingBefore?
(in NSMutableParagraphStyle)

Img Please.

I can't understanding for english...

[url : here click img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8Av4.gif)

Where is paragraphSpacingBefore ?

Answer (score 0):

***paragraphSpacing***
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMutableParagraphStyle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMutableParagraphStyle/paragraphSpacing

"This property contains the space (measured in points) **added at the end** of the paragraph to separate it from the following paragraph."

---

***paragraphSpacingBefore***
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMutableParagraphStyle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMutableParagraphStyle/paragraphSpacingBefore

This property contains the space (measured in points) **between the paragraph’s top and the beginning** of its text content.